# Error when passing one function to another TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, function

Whenever I try to pass my function another function I get this typeError,as I need to use my first function in the parameters of this one how can I solve this??

```
    def classify_playlist(func):
        spotify=pd.read_csv('../OUTPUT/spotify.csv')
        spotify.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'],inplace=True)
        spotify.columns
        y = spotify['intervals'].values
        X = spotify[['danceability', 'energy',
                'loudness',  'speechiness', 'acousticness',
               'instrumentalness', 'liveness', 'valence']].values
        X_train, X_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2)
    
    
        forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200)
        forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
        tx=func[['danceability', 'energy',
                'loudness',  'speechiness', 'acousticness',
               'instrumentalness', 'liveness', 'valence']].values
        testdata= forest.predict(tx)
        return testdata
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-107-4b5cd6f1b86c> in <module>
    ----> 1 b=classify_playlist(analyze_playlist)
          2 b
    
    <ipython-input-106-9d76177b031c> in classify_playlist(func)
         12     forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200)
         13     forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
    ---> 14     tx=func[['danceability', 'energy',
         15             'loudness',  'speechiness', 'acousticness',
         16            'instrumentalness', 'liveness', 'valence']].values
    
    TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

The function im passing is this one,as I need to access part of the dataframe how can I do this?

````
    def analyze_playlist(*args):
        
        
        playlist_features_list = ["artist","track_name","track_id","danceability","energy","key","loudness","mode", "speechiness",'acousticness',"instrumentalness","liveness","valence","tempo", "duration_ms"]
        
        playlist_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = playlist_features_list)
        
       
        
        playlist_tracks = sp.playlist_tracks(*args)["items"]
        for track in playlist_tracks:
            
            playlist_features = {}
            
            playlist_features["artist"] = track["track"]["artists"][0]["name"]
            playlist_features["track_name"] = track["track"]["name"]
            playlist_features["track_id"] = track["track"]["id"]
            
        
            audio_features = sp.audio_features(playlist_features["track_id"])[0]
            for feature in playlist_features_list[3:]:
                playlist_features[feature] = audio_features[feature]
            
            
            track_df = pd.DataFrame(playlist_features, index = [0])
            playlist_df = pd.concat([playlist_df, track_df], ignore_index = True)
            
        return playlist_df```
````

Comment: If `func` is a function you call it with `func()` not `func[]`

Comment: well `func` is a function. What do you expect `func[...]` to do?